# How to turn verbs into present participles in English

Tags: javascript

What is the simplest way to turn verbs into present participles?

```
 Input | Expected Output
———————|—————————————————
  walk | walking
   run | running
   eat | eating
    do | doing
   lie | lying
  make | making
```

Comment: English doesn't have hard rules that are reliable so there would be too many edge cases for this to be accomplished reasonably by a regular expression.

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to have a big mapping of base forms onto irregular forms (like "run/lie" above) and then use the "regular" method (verb + ing) for everything that's not in your mapping... and then keep expanding the mapping as you keep finding more irregular verbs.   :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to accomplish this and your environment supports it, you should use a natural language processing engine. For JS, take a look at http://compromise.cool/

```js
var words = ['walk','run','eat','do','lie','make','warn'];
words.map(
  e => console.log( nlp(e).verbs().toGerund().out().split(' ')[1] )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/compromise"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite sophisticated, I can't think of any simple way to do this task.

We would be approaching it by considering *all might want an `ing`*, then as our cases come up, we would be adding other rules, such as in this case, for `run` and `lie`:

```
((ru(n))|(l(ie)))
```

altered by

```
(.+)
```

we would be having:

```
((ru(n))|(l(ie)))|(.+)
```

then we would make the replacements.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0HZp2A/1/)